# PHP for loop with array and array slice functions

Tags: php, for-loop

As part of an expense data analyze, I am trying to find out top 3 expense categories for each month.Right now I have 3 months data : Array `$month0,$month1,$month3`.

Right now I am using below code and its working fine

```
$month0 = array("Bank"=>$Bank[0], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[0], "Loan"=>$Loan[0],"Household"=>$Household[0],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[0]);  
$month1 = array("Bank"=>$Bank[1], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[1], "Loan"=>$Loan[1],"Household"=>$Household[1],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[1]);  
$month2 = array("Bank"=>$Bank[2], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[2], "Loan"=>$Loan[2],"Household"=>$Household[2],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[2]);  

arsort($month0 ); 
arsort($month1 ); 
arsort($month2 ); 

$top3month0 = array_slice($month0, 0, 3); 
$top3month1 = array_slice($month1, 0, 3); 
$top3month2 = array_slice($month2, 0, 3); 

foreach ($top3month0 as $category => $amount){  
    $cat_top3month0[] = $category;  
    $amt_top3month0[] = $amount;
} 

foreach ($top3month1 as $category => $amount){  
    $cat_top3month1[] = $category;  
    $amt_top3month1[] = $amount;
} 

foreach ($top3month2 as $category => $amount){  
    $cat_top3month2[] = $category;  
    $amt_top3month2[] = $amount;
} 

//For Month0

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month0[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month0[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month0[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[2];

//For Month1

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month1[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month1[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month1[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[2];

//For Month3

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month2[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month2[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month2[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[2];
```

I am trying to use `for loop` here to reduce the length of the code. I changed above code like below using for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){

$month[i] = array("Bank"=>$Bank[i], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[i], "Loan"=>$Loan[i],"Household"=>$Household[i],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[i]);  

arsort($month[i] ); 

$top3month[i] = array_slice($month[i], 0, 3); 

foreach ($top3month[i] as $category => $amount){  
    $cat_top3month[i][] = $category;  
    $amt_top3month[i][] = $amount;
} 

}

//For Month0

/echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month0[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[0];
/echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month0[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[1];
/echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month0[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[2];

//For Month1

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month1[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month1[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month1[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[2];

//For Month3

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month2[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month2[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month2[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[2];
```

But above code is not working. When looking at the debug log I see below error

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

against line

```
$month[i] = array("Bank"=>$Bank[i], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[i], "Loan"=>$Loan[i],"Household"=>$Household[i],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[i]);
```

I am new to PHP and still learning. Can someone please tell me the issue with code ? or suggest a better approach to this ?

**Update:**

Updated the code to correct `i` to `$i`

```
for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){

$month[$i] = array("Bank"=>$Bank[$i], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[$i], "Loan"=>$Loan[$i],"Household"=>$Household[$i],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[$i]);  

arsort($month[$i] ); 

$top3month[$i] = array_slice($month[$i], 0, 3); 

foreach ($top3month[$i] as $category => $amount){  
    $cat_top3month[$i][] = $category;  
    $amt_top3month[$i][] = $amount;
} 

}

//For Month0

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month0[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month0[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month0[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month0[2];

//For Month1

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month1[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month1[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month1[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month1[2];

//For Month3

echo "Top 1 category is ".$cat_top3month2[0]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[0];
echo "Top 2 category is ".$cat_top3month2[1]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[1];
echo "Top 3 category is ".$cat_top3month2[2]." and amount: ".$amt_top3month2[2];
```

Now I have below errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in
```

against line :

```
$month[$i] = array("Bank"=>$Bank[$i], "CreditCard"=>$CreditCard[$i], "Loan"=>$Loan[$i],"Household"=>$Household[$i],"Utilities"=>$Utilities[$i]);
```

and

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Only variables can be passed by reference in
```

against `arsort($month[$i] );`

Comment: `i` should be `$i`, so `$month[i]` should be `$month[$i]`

Comment: @code-kobold:Thanks. I updated the code. Now I have errors mentioned in updated section